# Tortoise CVS checkout problem

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

I am little stumped while using TortoiseCVS. I have setup CVS server on a Ubuntu server and then initiated a repository under projects folder. Which created a CVSROOT folder as expected (projects/CVSROOT). Then created a directory structure under the projects folder and copied whole bunch of files in the new directory tree. The reason I did this is most of the files wouldn't be monitored by CVS.

So the new directory tree looks like this:

```
projects
  -CVSROOT
  -subproject1
    -admin
    -reports
  -subproject2
    -admin
    -software
```

...and so on

Now I would like to use tortoiseCVS from a windows machine and checkout the reports folder but when I try I get "cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory" error.

I thought this may be because I didn't do an add or import for the directory tree through CVS. But when use cygwin and do a checkout using command line I get no problem and I can get a copy of the desired folder/module.

If then through command line I add/commit a file into say the reports folder only then I am able  to checkout that module through TortoiseCVS, but other wise I can't.

I could add a temp file to each directory through command line but I really don't want to do that.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Manny

Comment: So `subproject1` is a direct subfolder of `projects` and `CVSROOT` is empty?

Comment: Yes, the subproject1 is a direct subfolder of projects and no the CVSROOT isn't empty it has its standard list of files (and an Emptydir) in it including the passwd file, because CVS is setup to use pserver.